# What happened to Facebook Video Call to action API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our service gives our users the possibility to upload videos to various social media networks, including Facebook Pages. We added to option to include call to actions at the end of their videos, which I'm pretty positive was available via the API and was listed as one of the fields of the video object in Page context.

The structure of the CTA JSON field we send is shown below:

```
{"call_to_action" : { "value" : {"type" : {CTA_TYPE}, "link" : {CTA_URL}}}
```

Now, I don't see this structure in the API description at all (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/). The API changed recently to version 2.7. We followed 2.6 but the fields are gone there as well.

We haven't gotten any alerts on the Facebook Developers dashboard and I can't seem to find any information on the CTAs anywhere. However, it seems that the CTAs are now only available for ad videos and can't be added to ordinary ones. The option is also no longer available in Facebook itself, i.e. when I upload the video manually.

Is this official? Have CTAs been removed from Facebook Videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have CTAs been removed from Facebook Videos?

Yes, it looks like they have:

> "After considering a number of factors, we have removed the option to add a CTA to the end of native video," said a spokeswoman for the social network.

http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-36586021

Comment: Ah, BBC interviews - the best source of information for developers :) Thanks!